# Plotting two variables function

Tags: algorithm

This question is for learning  purpose. I am writing my own function to plot an equation. For example:

```
function e(x) { return sin(x); }
plot(e);
```

I wrote a plot function that takes function as parameter. The plotting code is simple, x run from some value to some value and increase by small step. This is plot that the `plot()` manage to produce.

[image]

But there is the problem. It cannot  express the circle equation like x<sup>2</sup> + y<sup>2</sup> = 1. So the question would be how should  the plot and equation function  look  like to be able to handle two variables.

Noted that I am not only interesting in two circle equation. A more generalize way of plotting function with two variables.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: You'll have to solve the equation for one value. E.g.: `x²+y² = 1` is equivalent to `y=sqrt(x² + 1)`. This may be easier to achieve by simply plugging in the values for one variable and then solving the equation. What may be trickier though is that for one `x` there are two `y`-values for most parts of the equation.

Comment: @SardarUsama, I am using Canvas and Javascript, but I just need algorithm or the right pointer to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well to plot a non function 1D equation (`x,y` variables) you have 3 choices:

1. **convert to parametric form**

   so for example `x^2 + y^2 = 1` will become:

   ```
   x = cos(t);
   y = sin(t);
   t = <0,2*PI>
   ```

   So plot each function as 1D function plot while `t` is used as parameter.  But for this you need to exploit mathematic identities and substitute ... That is not easily done programaticaly.
2. **convert to 1D functions**

   non function means you got more than `1` `y` values for some `x` values. If you separate your equation into intervals and divide to all cases covering whole plot then you can plot each derived function instead.

   So you derive `y` algebraicaly (let assume unit circle again):

   ```
   x^2 + y^2 = 1
   y^2 = 1 - x^2
   y = +/- sqrt (1 - x^2)
   ----------------------
   y1 = +sqrt (1 - x^2)
   y2 = -sqrt (1 - x^2)
   x = <-1,+1>
   ```

   this is also not easily done programaticaly but it is a magnitude easier than **#1**.
3. **do a 2D plot using equation as predicator**

   simply loop your view through all pixels and render only those for which the equation is true. So again unit circle:

   ```cpp
   for (x=-1.0;x<=+1.0;x+=0.001)
    for (y=-1.0;y<=+1.0;y+=0.001)
     if (fabs((x*x)+(y*y)-1.0)<=1e-6)
      plot_pixel(x,y,some_color); // x,y should be rescaled and offset to the actual plot view
   ```

   So you just convert your equation to implicit form:

   ```
   x^2 + y^2 = 1
   -----------------
   x^2 + y^2 - 1 = 0
   ```

   and compare to zero with some threshold (to avoid FPU accuracy problems):

   ```
   | x^2 + y^2 - 1 | <= threshold_near_zero
   ```

   The threshold is half size of plot lines width. So this way you can easily change plot width to any pixel size... As you can see this is easily done programaticaly but the plot is slower as you need to loop through all the pixels of the plot view. The step for `x,y` `for` loops should match pixel size of the view scale.

   Also while using equation as predicate you should handle math singularities as with blind probing you will most likely hit some like division by zero, domain errors for `asin,acos,sqrt`,etc.

So for arbitrary **1D** non function use **#3**. unless you got some mighty symbolic math engine for **#1** or **#2**.

Answer (score 1):

Defination of a function : A function f takes an input x, and returns a single output f(x).

Now it means for any input there will be one and only one unique output. Like `y = sin(x)`. this is a function on `x` and `y` definnes that function.

For equaltion like `(x*x) + (y*y) = 1`. there are two possible values of `y` for a single value of `x,  hence it can not be termed as a valid equaltion for a function.

If you need to draw it then one possible solution is to plot two points for a single value of `x`, i.e. `sqrt(1-(x*x))` and other `-1*sqrt(1-(x*x))`. Plot both the values (one will be positive other will be negative with the same absolute value).

Comment: But let say the  two variables function get more complicated. Like y^3 + y^2 = x^2 + 2.

Comment: you will need a way to solve the value of y so that you can get all the possible values of x. then you will have to draw each correspondimg points for same x and different values of y.

Comment: may be you can see http://algebra.js.org Some way you need to solve for x then you need to plot those values

Comment: Interesting link. I will check ^^